# An inequality regarding a recursive relation

Tags: linear-algebra, inequalities

I have the following problem. I will be thankful for receiving any hint or any comments.

Suppose $p\in(0,1)$ and $q=1-p$. Given the recursive relation: for $n>k$, 
$$h(n)=q h(n-1)+p q^{k-1} h(n-k)$$
together with the boundary conditions: $h(0)=h(1)=0$
and for $n>1$, $n\leq k$: 
$$h(n)=(n-1)p^2q^{n-2}.$$
Prove that for $n\geq k$, we have
$$h(n)\geq q^{k-1} h(n-k+1).$$

Comment: The way this question is phrased makes it look like an exercise...

Comment: No conditions are given on $p$ and $q$ either.

Comment: You are right, I forgot to mention that 1>p>0 and q=1-p.

Comment: It seems then the problem came from some probability study. Can you give motivation?

Comment: Actually, I am performing research on the probability of the occurrence of a run of successes (consecutive k-out-of-n systems). I came across a paper that brings the above problem as an obvious fact and I don't see the proof.

Answer (score 2):

If you make the substitution $h(k) = u(k) q^k,$ then your recurrence becomes 
$$u(n) = u(n-1) + \frac{p}{q} u(n-k),$$ and you want to prove that the sequence of $u$s is non-decreasing.

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance. I hope to be able to use this for some more general.

Comment: I try the substitution and get something different, involving p/q and proving u(n) is at least u(n-k).  Are you using 1=p+q?  Gerhard "Also Minds R's And S's" Paseman, 2016.10.05.

Comment: Yes. You get the coefficient of (p/q) instead of p. Anyhow, this doesn't matter.As I noted in a further comment, q=1-p. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: @Igor: should it be $u(n) = u(n-1) + p q^{-1}u(n-k)$.

Comment: Igor, Amdeberhan: It seems that this is correct. Thank you . As I mentioned, I actually hope to carry out some generalization.